# css same code 2 different result

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a problem with css...
i use a greasemonkey script for edit a site and add a button + menu
here the code:

```
function menuStile() {
    st = document.createElement('style');
    st.setAttribute('type','text/css');
    st.innerHTML = '#ScriptMenuOpzioni {               ' +    
        'position:relative;                          ' +  
        '}                                           ' +  
        '#ScriptMenuOpzioni #MenuScript{               ' +  
        'position:absolute;                          ' +  
        'background:#FFF;                            ' +  
        'top:100%;'+    
        'margin:0;                                   ' +  
        'padding:10px;                               ' +   
        'z-index:1001;'+  
        'left:0;'+  
        'width:120%;'+  
        'font-family: \'Exo 2\', sans-serif;         ' +  
        'color:#000; }                               ' +  
        '#ScriptMenuOpzioni:hover #MenuScript,#ScriptMenuOpzioni #MenuScript:hover{          ' +  
        'visibility:visible;                         ' +  
        ' }';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(st);
}
```

this is the js script of the css (i edited it a bit for remove other css not involved in that part so maybe u can find js error... but is correct :-P )
the html of the code is this:

```
<center>
<span id="ScriptMenuOpzioni">
<input type="button" value="Menu Script" id="ScriptMenuOpzioni">
<div id="MenuScript">
<nav><li><input type="button" value="Apri PM"></li><li><a href="board/search.php?do=process&amp;exactname=1&amp;showposts=1">Mostra Post</a></li> <li><a href="search.php?do=process&amp;exactname=1&amp;starteronly=1&amp;showposts=0">Mostra Thread</a></li> </nav>
</div>
</span>
</center>
```

now the code is always the same but i get 2 different results
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30396291/LOL/menuscript.png
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30396291/LOL/menuscriptbug.png
when the "bugged" version get loaded the div start from the `<center>` tab instead the `<span>`
when the right version get loaded start from the `<span>`
when this happen the menu is bigger and is separated from the button by a pixel and i can't move the mouse from #ScriptMenuOpzioni to #MenuScript bc it exit and the #MenuScript lost the visibility
i don't understand when this happen because i use firefox for debug and chrome normally.... but when i try to debug i never get this problem -.- and happen sometimes with chrome (or maybe happen only with chrome? O.o )

any hint?

PS i tried to copy the entire code html (when i get the bug) on jsfiddle and it works...

Comment: my eyes are paining. pls format ur code.

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated. Better use CSS `text-align: center`.

Comment: @Gaurav i just used copy paste :-P now i'll edit it :-P

Comment: @Oriol i tried to remove the center tag... i'll see what happen ... (the problem is random so i can't know for sure if is solved or not :-P ) *edit*  
nothing same problem... it gets the width from the parent.parent instead the parent....

Comment: @Trigun Sorry for the confusion, my comment was unrelated to your problem. But you shouldn't use `<center>`.

Comment: @Oriol i know the probability was low .. but i still tried ^_^

Comment: can u post the link to thate fiddle?

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto can't post 3 link with my reputation :-P umm maybe i can post here for comments http://jsfiddle.net/AKMd5/ this is the code in a page... but works like the first image